# How to change runnable code in thread after starting thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Suppose I have a service whose startcommand method looks like this

```
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {  
final String s= intent.getStringExtra("time"); // s contains some time in hh:mm:ss format

Runnable r=new Runnable{
                public void run(){
                      String[] parts = s.split(":");
                      Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
                      //wait till current time is same as time received from intent
                      while(!(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) == current.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) &&
                              Integer.parseInt(parts[1]) == current.get(Calendar.MINUTE) )  )
                        {  current=Calendar.getInstance();  }
                       // do something after loop
                      }
Thread t= new Thread(r);
t.start();
return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Now if I called startService more than once in my activity, I figured out that multiple threads were created.
Suppose I had called startservice twice with different intents, and at some point in my program I required to change the condition in the while loop of the first thread, how do i do it?

Comment: It depends on the kind of change you need to make. As a general solution you may want to look into the Strategy design pattern.

Comment: I don't know Android, but one "service" that does either one of two different things sounds like a violation of SRP.

Answer (score 0):

> I required to change the condition in the while loop.

So, how about you encapsulate the condition in a `@FunctionalInterface`, and pass it in to the service as a lambda?